# How to dynamicly set boder color for list item?

Tags: java, android, border

I have a ListView which has RelativeLayout as elements inside of it. I want to set different color for every item's right border based on item's data. I understand that I will probably need something like this to create borders:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke android:width="2dp" android:height="2dp"
                android:color="#FF0000" />
            <solid android:color="#000000" />
            <padding android:left="1dp" android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp"
                android:bottom="1dp" />

            <corners android:radius="1dp" android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
                android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp" android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
                android:topRightRadius="0dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

But I don't know how to set color for each individual element.

Answer (score 0):

You need your [own custom Adapter](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#listview_adapterown) and [XML-Drawables](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape) which display the shape you need. In the [getView-Method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29) of your adapter you dynamically add the drawable to your returned View. Hope that helps!

Comment: I already have a custom adapter and I am handling getView method. Could you elaborate how could I dynamically create XML-drivales?